# Date compare with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to compare current date with the one stored in db and I am using the following code for this

```
<script>
$("#registerButton").click(function() {
var first = $("#scantime").val();
var second = $("#scanbartime").val();
if (parseInt(first.replace(/-/g,""),10) > parseInt(second.replace(/-/g,""),10)){
        alert("Ticket has Expired");
    }
    else {
    var signintime =$("#scantime").val();
    var id = $("#id").val();
var y = new Date();
var y1=y.getFullYear() + "-" +(y.getMonth()+1) + "-" + y.getDate();
y.setHours(y.getHours()+4);
y1 = y1 + "  " + y.getHours()+ ":" + y.getMinutes() + ":" + y.getSeconds();
document.getElementById('scanbartime').value = y1;
var expdate=y1;
       $.ajax({
            url: "updatescan.php",
            method: "POST",
       data: {signintime:signintime,expdate:expdate,id:id} , 
dataType:"text",   
            success: function(data)
                        {                   
                        }
        });
    }
    });
</script>
```

The format of scantime Is like 2016-5-26  21:31:13 and the format of scanbartime is like 2016-05-26 17:31:11.000000 so why I'm using parseint . 
My problem is that alert wont be enabled if first is greater than second 
I have also tried

```
 if (first > second)
```

but also the alert wont be enabled 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create Javascript date object and set the value by parsing first and second and then compare:

```
> var first = new Date('2016-5-26 21:31:13')
> var second = new Date('2016-05-26 17:31:11.000000')
> first > second
true
```

Comment: values of scantime and scanbartime are echoed from the db

Comment: "2016-5-26 21:31:13" you have this value, so you can split this into 2arrays. Then split again by "-" and ":" Set your firstDateObject with these values. Same thing for second.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following:

```
The format of scantime Is like 2016-5-26 21:31:13 and the format of scanbartime is like 2016-05-26 17:31:11.000000
```

This is how you can turn those strings into valid Date object formats and then compare the Date object

```
// Turn 2016-5-26 21:31:13 into valid Date string to parse
var time1 = '2016-5-26 21:31:13';
time1 = time1.split(' ');
var split= time1[0].split('-');
for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
  if( split[i] < 10 )
    split[i] = '0'+split[i];
}
var date1 = new Date(split.join('-') + 'T' + time1[1]);

// Turn 2016-05-26 17:31:11.000000 into a valid Date string
// The zeroes at the end dont matter
var time2 = '2016-05-26 17:31:11.000000';
time2 = time2.replace(' ', 'T');
var date2 = new Date(time2);

// Compare the dates
console.log(date1 < date2); // False
console.log(date2 < date1); // True
```

From what I witnessed the key takeway is that the month and day should be **zero-padded** and the space between the two strings should have a **T**. The extra trailing zeroes for miliseconds in the second string are irrelevant.

Comment: it doesn't work maybe is missing { on if if( split[i] < 10 )